# sending messages to a contract using geth

Tags: go-ethereum, presale

I have a working system for minting tokens and transferring them as follows -

```
> addrtoken.balanceOf(eth.accounts[0])
33333250
> addrtoken.balanceOf(eth.accounts[1])
50
```

I want to test the buyTokens function. The function uses msg.value and I am unsure how to test that. Here is the func below. Is there a way to send the msg.value in geth?

```
 // fallback function to buy tokens
 function () payable {
   buyTokens(msg.sender);
 }

  /**
   * Low level token purchse function
    * @param beneficiary will recieve the tokens.
   */
  function buyTokens(address beneficiary) payable whenNotPaused {
    require(beneficiary != 0x0);
  require(validPurchase());


uint256 weiAmount = msg.value;
// update weiRaised
weiRaised = weiRaised.add(weiAmount);
// compute amount of tokens created
uint256 tokens = weiAmount.mul(rate);

token.mint(beneficiary, tokens);
TokenPurchase(msg.sender, beneficiary, weiAmount, tokens);
forwardFunds();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function of `buyToken` called by fallback function. So you must trigger fallback function, as follows on `geth` console:

```
eth.sendTransaction({from:eth.coinbase,to:addrtoken.address,value:10})
```

About fallback function, please read this [fallback](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-is-the-deal-with-function-inside-solidity-contracts-how-can-a-function-not-have-a-name)

Hope it helps~

Comment: This does not work for me. Just says - Line 1:29 Unexpected identifier (and 3 more errors) - line 29 is an add function - I think it is trying to add the value to total raised. It is not understanding the value correctly.

Comment: Sorry, it's my fault. I ignore fallback function, i updated answer.

Comment: This is just a transfer of eth? I am using tokens.

Comment: At first, you must understand when [fallback](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/frequently-asked-questions.html#what-is-the-deal-with-function-inside-solidity-contracts-how-can-a-function-not-have-a-name) function is called. If you transfer ether to your contract, fallback function would automatically be called, and then `buyToken` function would be invoked. So users can buy your tokens when users transfer ether to your contract. You should try it on geth console.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
MyToken.deployed().then(function(instance) { return instance.buyToken('0x0ab768ac22111fdd177085238a7b51f6270497d0','0x38a1f9f495fdef18f18073eef329945316a5d281',100);}).then(console.log());
```